# Missing folder in Microsoft Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

When I was moving mail from my inbox to an another folder, some dragging confusion happened and I lost my one of the folders. When I expanded all the folders and searched for it but I could not find it.

When I search the mail that was present in the folder, I am able to access those. I am not able to create a new folder with the name that was held by the folder that disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Close and reopen Outlook, it sounds like it needs to reindex the .PST

If that doesn't work, next would be to run [ScanPST (Inbox Repair Tool)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272227) to repair the PST.